# Science fiction book in the mid-1980s about medically/drug enhanced soldiers fighting a war

Tags: story-identification, warfare

I thought it was called "The Drug War" but I can't find that anywhere. I remember the main character lives in a society where the citizens are well off and drug use is rampant.  He decides to join the military. He comes home and finds his dad floating in the pool dead from suicide.

Comment: More details please: who does he fight for/against? In which position (infantry/marine/pilot)? Does he fight in Earth/space/other planets? Technology level?